# Rust way to transfer ownership while guaranteeing no underlying data copy

Tags: pointers, rust, reference, memcpy, ownership

I am a bit confused about how to transfer ownership without the overhead of actual data copy.
I have the following code. I am referring to underlying data copy by OS as memcopy.

```
fn main() {
    let v1 = Vec::from([1; 1024]);
    take_ownership_but_memcopies(v1);

    let v2 = Vec::from([2; 1024]);
    dont_memecopy_but_dont_take_ownership(&v2);

    let v3 = Vec::from([3; 1024]);
    take_ownership_dont_memcopy(???);
}

// Moves but memcopies all elements
fn take_ownership_but_memcopies(my_vec1: Vec<i32>) {
    println!("{:?}", my_vec1);
}

// Doesn't memcopy but doesn't take ownership
fn dont_memecopy_but_dont_take_ownership(my_vec2: &Vec<i32>) {
    println!("{:?}", my_vec2);
}

// Take ownership without the overhead of memcopy
fn take_ownership_dont_memcopy(myvec3: ???) {
    println!("{:?}", my_vec3);
}
```

As i understand, if i use reference like v2, i don't get the ownership. If i use it like v1, there could be a memcopy.

How should i need to transfer v3 to guarantee that there is no underlying memcopy by OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of what happens when you move a `Vec` is incorrect - it does not copy every element within the `Vec`!

To understand why, we need to take a step back and look at how a `Vec` is represented internally:

```rust
// This is slightly simplified, look at the source for more details!

struct Vec<T> {
    pointer: *mut T, // pointer to the data (on the heap)
    capacity: usize, // the current capacity of the Vec
    len: usize,      // the current number of elements in the Vec
}
```

While the `Vec` conceptually 'owns' the elements, they are not stored within the `Vec` struct - it only holds a pointer to that data. So when you move a `Vec`, it is only the pointer (plus the capacity and length) that gets copied.

---

If you are attempting to avoid copying *altogether*, as opposed to avoiding copying the contents of the `Vec`, that isn't really possible - in the semantics of the compiler, a move *is* a copy (just one that prevents you from using the old data afterwards). However, the compiler can and will optimize trivial copies into something more efficient.

Comment: thanks. does it also work if i need to transfer a large struct? for ex. let s1 = Struct LargeStruct {element1, element2, ..... element1024,}  ?

Comment: If the data is contained directly within the struct, then yes, that could potentially involve a large memcopy. If you find that this is causing you performance issues, you may benefit from wrapping the data in a `Box`, which will store the data behind a pointer to the heap like a `Vec` does.

Answer (score 1):

> How should i need to transfer v3 to guarantee that there is no underlying memcopy by OS?

You can't. Because that's Rust's semantics.

However a `Vec` is just 3 words on the stack, that's all which gets "memcopy"d, which is intrinsic, it's not like you're going to get a `memcpy` function call in there or duplicate the entire vector. And that's assuming the function call does not get inlined, and the compiler does not decide to pass in object as a reference anyway. It could also pass all 3 words through registers, at which point there's nothing to memcpy.

Though it's not entirely clear why you care either way, if you only want to read from the collection your function should be

```rust
// Take ownership without the overhead of memcopy
fn take_ownership_dont_memcopy(myvec3: &[i32]) {
    println!("{:?}", my_vec3);
}
```

that is the most efficient and flexible signature: it's just two words, there's a single pointer (unlike `&Vec`), and it allows for non-`Vec` sources.